# Which form control to use, for chat window

Tags: c#, forms, chat, irc

I'm writing a C Sharp IRC bot, with forms, and not console.
I'm kinda confused as to which control I should use, to display the text from the server/channel, as I'm fairly new to forms and all.

Also, if anyone knows of source code, of a c sharp bot, using forms, please don't hesitate to post it ^^

Thanks, Conlon.

Comment: Hey, I'd be interested in attempting a similar program as well, any chance I could contact you via AIM or something similar to work together on it?

Comment: @Walkerneo Yo!
That sounds cool, I'd like that.
I don't use AIM, I'm afraid. Either Steam or MSN!

Comment: Added you. I'd prefer Steam, but it's a hassle if you don't use it.

Comment: Yeah, I don't have Steam, but I downloaded Pidgin, which should allow us to chat. It should say I'm online, but let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: Alright, I downloaded Live Messenger as well, so if it says I'm still offline, then something may be amiss. What's your email?

Answer (score 1):

you could use a richtextbox.... it has a bit of a learning curve in order to use it really well,  but it is quite capable.

Another option if you just want simple text and you want to append a line at a time is a Listbox.

With both options, you will need to make sure you don't keep adding data without purging otherwise it will run out of memory.   So you may also wish to build a logging mechanisim also so you can have a file based history.

Comment: Care to elaborate on a few things?
Using this, when stuff is written to it, wouldn't it be saved over the existing text? Maybe I'm just confusing myself.

Comment: @Conlon, You would be able to access the text that's already in the control, and append any new text programmatically.

Comment: @Walkerneo, makes sense. I was just thinking in the lines of extra functions, used by this richtextbox or whatever.

Comment: Thanks for the help, @Keith.
I can't upvote you, I'm afraid :<

Answer (score 0):

You can use a text box and set it to multiline

Comment: But with a textbox, woulnd't it write over the last text?
I mean, how would the text be stored?

Comment: I just found this example from another question it give your the code to create your own chat with client and server http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial239_Csharp-Chat-Part-1---Building-the-Chat-Client.html